# Can I do this with bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Quick question -

I'm developing a product that will receive data from an android phone via bluetooth. Are there any restrictions on the data that I can transfer? I'm thinking anything from text to images.

I'm inexperienced, just want to know the feasibility. THanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Bluetooth API Reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html) might be of help for you. To answer your question in short: You could send any data while you might need your own form to serialize them.